# How to detect HorizontalListView scroll end

Tags: android, listview, horizontal-scrolling

I have use HorizontalListView from this [web](https://github.com/vieux/Android-Horizontal-ListView/blob/master/HorizontalListView.java) but I don't know how to measure state of scroll.

Because I want to create HorizontalListView that automatically adjust when some element is half-visible **after scrolling finishes**.

```
     000|111 222 333|444

     0|00 111 222 3|33 444 --> |000 111 222|333

     11|1 222 333 44|4 555 --> 111|222 333 444|555
```

I have try to set

```
if(mScroller.isFinished() && isFling){
     // adjust 
}
```

but that leave a problem when `onFling` is not called.

but if I used `ACTION_UP` if it has Fling then it becomes mess.

Any suggestion to achieve this?
Thank for every help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try modifying the code of the developer to get the current position of the list item by setting the Tag of any one of the object [TextView, Image etc], then comparing the same with your count or max count by getCount method of the Adapter.